# Use of "this" or "these" when speaking of something invariable and something variable at the same time

Tags: word-usage, sentence

Hello everyone and thanks in advance for your help.

I've come across this sentence while correcting a document for my workplace:

"All these data and relationships have been gathered"

I've been wondering if "All these" or "All this" is appropriate.
Since "data" is invariable I would instinctively use "this", however since we are talking about "data and relationships" I'm quite confused.

I hope this enough detail to make you understand my dilema.

Comment: Strictly speaking, *data* is plural (of *datum,* a point of information).

Comment: I agree, strictly speaking that would be the case. However, in it's evey day usage it is used like a mass noun. I could replace the word "data" with "information" and ask exactly the same question.

Comment: {Data} is plural of {datum}. All these data. Not, All this data.

Comment: Your replacing {data} with {information}, is like replacing the word {chairs} with {furniture}. Your strategy of transforming a countable noun to a collective noun, is your own answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this a question of style? It would be unremarkable to say "All of these facts and relationships," but strange to say either "All of these information and relationships" or "All of this information and relationships." So if you feel that the word "data" has come to mean "information" then you should apparently say "This information and these relationships," or choose two words that agree in number.

Comment: I agree with you, it is probably for the best to say  "This information and these relationships," which is what I'm going to suggest at my workplace. However, I also agree that "Strictly speaking, data is plural (of datum, a point of information)", and I've got to thank @AndrewLeach for teaching me that. If by Wednesday 18/01/2017 he posts this as an answer I'm going to accept his answer, else wise your answer will be chosen. In any case thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing 'these' with 'the': 'All the data and relationships have been gathered.'

Comment: Just to let you know, this came up on the LQ queue. I did not recommend deletion, but someone sooner or later will.